# How can I see the most recent channels I have subscribed to on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

When you access the list of channels you are subscribed to, it lists them in alphabetical order.

https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels

I want to see them in chronological order.

Answer (score 6):

You can find them here.
YouTube [My history page](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history) > [Manage all history](https://myactivity.google.com/product/youtube?hl=en&utm_medium=web&utm_source=youtube) > Interactions > [YouTube channel subscriptions](https://myactivity.google.com/page?utm_source=my-activity&hl=en&page=youtube_subscriptions).

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** This is no longer true (or maybe it is, if they change it again after I make this edit...)

**Old answer:**
If you have made your subscriptions public, you can go to `my channel > channels` and see your subscriptions in chronological order

Comment: It works for me, while I am logged in, even if the subscriptions are private and not public! URL is: https://www.youtube.com/user/<youruser>/channels?disable_polymer=1

Comment: They aren't in chronological order for me. Is there an option to show them in chronological order?

Comment: @Santropedro It doesn't seem to be ordered anymore. I guess the youtube AI algorithm god knows what's best for us better than we do. Actually mine looks completely random so I don't even know what the hell they are thinking

Comment: @user643011 this is not in chronological order...

Answer (score 4):

YouTube doesn't offer this feature currently. If you want to see it added, you may want to [send feedback](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4347644?hl=en).